# how do i further reduce the run time of this code

Tags: c++, time, reduce

how do i reduce the run time of this code and bring it below 3 sec. a and b vary from 1        to 10^9 and testcases from 1 to 100

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
static int testCases;

static int result[100];


int main()
{
  cin>>testCases;
  for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
    int a, b;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    int count = 0;
    while (a <= b) {
      double lim = sqrt(a);
      int special = 1;
      for (int z = 2; z <= lim; z++) {
        if (a % (z * z) == 0) {
          special = 0;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (special == 1)
        count++;

      a++;
    }
    result[i]=count;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    cout<<result[i]<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think this is one of that situations where a correct sourcecode aligment could improve the efficiency of the program at runtime (And compile-time, the compiler as a code reader will be much happier)

Comment: Why not indent the code to make it readable?

Comment: Here the answer to your question: Learn algorithms. How do you expect a three nested loops program be quickly at runtime?

Comment: (depending on how big `testCases` can get) the greatest speed-up will probably be gained by simply waiving that outer `for`-loop, cause it's not using `i` inside (except for storing the result of a test case) and thus the result of each cycle will always be the same...

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, here is one advice...

**Change this:**

```
while (a <= b)
{
    double lim = sqrt(a);
    ...
    a++;
}
```

**To this:**

```
int lim = (int)sqrt(a);
int max = (lim+1)*(lim+1);
while (a <= b)
{
    ...
    a++;
    if (a == max)
    {
        lim++;
        max = (lim+1)*(lim+1);
    }
}
```

In addition to saving the time spent on the execution of function `sqrt`, if you enable compiler optimizations in your project settings, then it might be able to apply loop-unrolling on the outer and/or inner loops, since there are no other function-calls inside these loops at this point.

---

Another advice would be to perform the test for `z=2` and `z=3` separately, and from that point onwards, test only `z=6N-1` and `z=6N+1` (i.e., **all** numbers which are neither a multiple of 2 nor a multiple of 3):

```
while (a <= b)
{
    int special = 1;
    if (a%4 == 0 || a%9 == 0)
    {
        special = 0;
    }
    else for (int z=5,c=2; z<=lim; z+=c,c=6-c)
    {
        if (a % (z * z) == 0)
        {
            special = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you know that after `lim++`, `max == lim*lim`, depending on the specific compiler and processor, it may be advantageous to change `max = (lim+1)*(lim+1)` to `max += 2*lim+1`.

Comment: @hvd: I thought about it, but in terms of performance, there is no gain in `max += 2*lim+1` over `max = (lim+1)*(lim+1)`, as the `+=` yields another load operation (loading the value of `max` before updating it). In fact, it will probably cause the compiler to add a few `nop`s because the "loading from max" being followed by a "storing into max".

Comment: @Manu343726 The square root does depend on things in the loop, that's why this answer does still update `lim` inside the loop, but it manages to do so without calling the `sqrt` function again.

Comment: @barakmanos Like I said, it depends on the specific compiler and processor. It avoids a multiplication (2*lim can be calculated by a shift), and depending on the specific system, that may be a higher win than the loss you describe. But I wouldn't expect any `nop`s.

Comment: @hvd: Still, there is an additional "load max" operation in what you suggest.